# Can prepositional phrases describe how something is after action?

Tags: sentence-construction

Can “a dog barked at me out of the place” describe a dog barked at me and after then, I ran out of the place?

Comment: Neither of these sentences are acceptable English. Dogs don't "yell". "Woundedly" is an adverb, usually used to describe someone's feelings, e.g., "He derided her, and she looked back woundedly."

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik I renewed the question.

Comment: "The teacher yelled me out of the classroom" is possible, but your current example sentence doesn't work. Maybe someone else can say why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in your example. The sentence isn't great English, but I suppose it would mean that the dog was in the place and the barking was coming from the place at you, who was standing outside the place.

There are some verbs like "drive" that form a phrasal verb "drive out".  So it is correct to say

> The dog drove me out of the place.

quite a lot of speaking verbs can be used like this:

> The headteacher called me out of the classroom to come to her office.

So "barked me out" to mean "drove me out by barking" might be understood, but its not really idiomatic.

The best way is just to use "and" or "so"

> The dog barked at me, so I quickly left the place.